# Making a query inside another query in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have executions and each execution has several images, example,

table execution

```
 id |    name
 1   execution1
```

table image

```
id |   executionId | image
1          1          'path'
2          1          'path2'
```

I want a query that get all the executions, with each execution having all their images like,

```
  { executions: [
         { id: 1,
           name: execution1,
           images: [
                'path',
                'path2'
             ]
          },
         {...}
      ]
 }
```

Comment: Sounds like an INNER JOIN.

Comment: But yo wont get that output from a single query, you will have to do a little jiggery pokery in the code that processes the result

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.id, e.name, i.image  
  FROM executions e 
  JOIN image i ON e.name = i.executionId;
```

As @RiggsFolly mentioned in comment, your code then needs to parse the response into the format you're after.